# Can markdown expressions and results be interleaved in the same block?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

A simple chunk in R markdown:

````
```{r}
1 + 2
3 + 4
```
````

Would produce the following when knitr converts to html:

```
<pre><code class="r">1 + 2</code></pre>
<pre><code>## 3</code></pre>

<pre><code class="r">3 + 4</code></pre>
<pre><code>## 7</code></pre>
```

I'm trying to output the expressions and results in one block

```
<pre><code class="r">
1 + 2
## 3
3 + 4
## 7
</code></pre>
```

I've tried tinkering around with the chunk parameters (e.g. results and echo) to no avail. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Note: I could probably hack at CSS with `::first` and `::last` selectors, but I'm curious as to whether there's a built-in option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using `hooks`. Add the following code chunk right at the top of your `Rmd` document. It uses the document hook which is run on the `md` file at the last stage of `knitting`. The hook defined below identifies subsequent code chunks without any text chunk in between and collapses it into one.

````
```{r setup, cache = F, echo = F}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(document = function(x){ 
  gsub("```\n*```r*\n*", "", x) 
})
```
````

NOTE. It is important to set `cache = F` in this chunk so that this code is always run.

Comment: I'll add that you should also add `echo = FALSE`. Otherwise, that function will appear at the top of every file. Thanks for the answer!